WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 20.04 in HP ZBook
This question is similar to 1 and 2 with a minor difference. I have referred to both questions but with no success. Below are the details:
This is a brand new HP ZBook laptop with an Intel i7 processor, and I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on it. There are the following issues with it:

Screen brightness control keys are not working
The WiFi adaptor is not recognized

It was shipped with Windows. So first of all, I updated BIOS and Chipset drivers from Windows OS. Later I deleted the Windows partition and tried installing Ubuntu. The default installation option did not work as the laptop screen seems stuck with the following log:
RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nune0n1p2: clean, 197903/62480384 files, 6833111/249919744 blocks

Later, I could install Ubuntu with the "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" option. However both the issues mentioned above persist. Below are the system details:
Hardware Info
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:610-60f memory:614d1d4000-614d1d7fff

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8b41]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

 $ lspci | grep -i network
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f1 (rev 01)

Kernel and OS Info
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:52:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Kernel Log
$ sudo dmesg | grep firmware
[   26.086751] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[   26.263133] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[   27.852144] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete

Any workaround, please?

Might be easier to use Ubuntu 24.04 with the newer kernel

@Jeremy31: Thats right. But due to a project requirement (+ other dependencies), I am stuck with Ubuntu 20.04. I do feel that it is a kernel 5.15 issue. I am thinking that ugrading kernel to 6.x may solve the issue. I haven't tried it though. BTW, do you have any other suggestion/workaround to make Ubuntu 20.04 work? Thanks a lot!

If Secure Boot is disabled, you could try installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms

Use the mainline kernel tool to update kernel version. https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Alternatively, install Ubuntu 24.04 to use all laptop features, and do your project in a VM running 20.04
